# Opposite of Swift `zip` — split tuple into two arrays

Tags: arrays, swift, tuples

I have an array of key-value pairs:

```
let arr = [(key:"hey", value:["ho"]), (key:"ha", value:["tee", "hee"])]
```

I'm splitting it into two arrays, like this:

```
let (keys, values) = (arr.map{$0.key}, arr.map{$0.value})
```

Effectively, that's the opposite of `zip` — I'm turning an array of tuples into two arrays.

But I don't like the fact that I'm calling `map` twice, because that means I'm looping through the array twice. Yet neither do I want to declare the two target arrays beforehand as empty arrays and loop once while appending, e.g. with `forEach`. Is there some wonderful Swifty idiom for unzipping my array of tuples into two arrays?

Comment: ... or Swift 4 using shorter initial values: `let (keys, values) = arr.reduce(into: ([], [])) { $0.0.append($1.key); $0.1.append($1.value) }`

Comment: Depending on what you need to do with the result, `.lazy.map` could be a good option. E.g. if you just need to iterate these seperately

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Swift 4, you can use `reduce(into:)`:

```
let (keys, values) = arr.reduce(into: ([String](), [[String]]())) {
    $0.0.append($1.key)
    $0.1.append($1.value)
}
```

You said:

> Yet neither do I want to declare the two target arrays beforehand as empty arrays and loop once while appending, e.g. with `forEach`.

Personally, that's precisely what I would do. I would just write a function that does this (that way you're not sprinkling your code with that pattern). But I think the following is much more clear and intuitive than the `reduce` pattern, but doesn't suffer the inefficiency of the dual-`map` approach.

```
/// Unzip an `Array` of key/value tuples.
///
/// - Parameter array: `Array` of key/value tuples.
/// - Returns: A tuple with two arrays, an `Array` of keys and an `Array` of values.

func unzip<K, V>(_ array: [(key: K, value: V)]) -> ([K], [V]) {
    var keys = [K]()
    var values = [V]()

    keys.reserveCapacity(array.count)
    values.reserveCapacity(array.count)

    array.forEach { key, value in
        keys.append(key)
        values.append(value)
    }

    return (keys, values)
}
```

Or, if you feel compelled to make it an `extension`, you can do that, too:

```
extension Array {

    /// Unzip an `Array` of key/value tuples.
    ///
    /// - Returns: A tuple with two arrays, an `Array` of keys and an `Array` of values.

    func unzip<K, V>() -> ([K], [V]) where Element == (key: K, value: V) {
        var keys = [K]()
        var values = [V]()

        keys.reserveCapacity(count)
        values.reserveCapacity(count)

        forEach { key, value in
            keys.append(key)
            values.append(value)
        }

        return (keys, values)
    }
}
```

Implement this however you'd like, but when you have it in a function, you can favor clarity and intent.

Comment: Don't forget to `reserveCapacity` to prevent reallocation

Comment: @matt - Re `reduce(into:)`, in WWDC 2017 [What's New in Swift 4](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/402/), they directed us to [Ole Begemann's playground](https://github.com/ole/whats-new-in-swift-4). That's where I came across it.

Comment: You could also just make this an extension of `Sequence`; reserving `underestimatedCount`'s worth of capacity.

Comment: @Rob But it wasn't in fact present in beta 1.

Comment: @matt Specifically, it was added in the version of Swift that shipped with Xcode 9 beta 5

Comment: Ended up with `let (keys,values) : ([String], [[String]]) = arr.reduce(into: ([],[])) { acc, pair in acc.0.append(pair.0); acc.1.append(pair.1) }`, essentially a tweak on your original comment. I think it's clearer putting the types in the variable declaration, and names rather than numbers, but that's purely an aesthetic matter.

Comment: @Hamish yeah, that's what I wish they'd called out

Answer (score 9):

## Swift 4

`reduce(into:)` is great, but don't forget to `reserveCapacity` to prevent reallocation overhead:

```
extension Array {
    func unzip<T1, T2>() -> ([T1], [T2]) where Element == (T1, T2) {
        var result = ([T1](), [T2]())

        result.0.reserveCapacity(self.count)
        result.1.reserveCapacity(self.count)

        return reduce(into: result) { acc, pair in
            acc.0.append(pair.0)
            acc.1.append(pair.1)
        }
    }
}
```

## Prior to Swift 4

I would apply the KISS principle:

```
extension Array {
    func unzip<T1, T2>() -> ([T1], [T2]) where Element == (T1, T2) {
        var result = ([T1](), [T2]())

        result.0.reserveCapacity(self.count)
        result.1.reserveCapacity(self.count)

        for (a, b) in self {
            result.0.append(a)
            result.1.append(b)
        }

        return result
    }
}

let arr = [
    (key: "hey", value: ["ho"]),
    (key: "ha",  value: ["tee", "hee"])
]

let unzipped = (arr as [(String, [String])]).unzip()
print(unzipped)
```

Answer (score 1):

Not pretty but the only thing I could come up with right now: using `reduce`:

```
let (keys, values) = arr.reduce(([], [])) { ($0.0.0 + [$0.1.key], $0.0.1 + [$0.1.value]) }
```

Would be a lot prettier without having to specify the initial values which add a lot of noise and make the code not easily.

Generified it already looks a bit cleaner:

```
func unzip<K,V>(_ array : [(K,V)]) -> ([K], [V]) {
    return array.reduce(([], [])) { ($0.0 + [$1.0], $0.1 + [$1.1])}
}

let (keys, values) = unzip(arr)
```

Comment: I came up with `let (keys, values) = arr.reduce(([],[])) {($0.0 + [$1.key], $0.1 + [$1.value])}`

Comment: This can be a legitimate way to go in Swift 4 with `reduce(into:)`, whose closure takes an `inout` parameter, but the normal Swift 3 version of `reduce` has *extremely* poor performance when building arrays using `reduce()` and the `+` operator, since it has to copy the whole array on each iteration of the loop.

Comment: @vacawama I *always* forget that `[]` works in these situations as well - added it in. And the shorter `$...` syntax did not work for me when playing around but it works in the end, thanks.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka I would very much understand if that is the case, I do not know though.

Comment: @luk2302 Try it yourself; build some arrays with 1,000,000 elements in them using a for loop and `reduce()`, and time it. In my testing, the performance hit with `reduce()` is so large that it can literally take over 10 minutes where a for loop takes around 0.01 seconds. It's completely impractical. See: https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20170116/030308.html

Comment: @CharlesSrstka make sure to test it ia a real project. Playground it is not thrust worthy

Comment: @Leo Dabus and Rob As I said in the mailing list post that I linked to, I *did* test it with the optimizations on. But by all means, don't take my word for it! Run the test yourself and see. There's code in the mailing list post.