# How to get keys and values from dictionary in same order?

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-dictionary

I am using a dictionary to store key-value pairs. It's storing correctly kay-value pair. But when I try to retrieve all keys and all values separately, it's printing different differently.

Here is the example,

```
    var sampleDic:[String:Any] = [:]
    sampleDic["one"] =  1
    sampleDic["two"] =  2
    sampleDic["three"] =  3

    print("keys: \(sampleDic.keys)")
    print("Values: \(sampleDic.values)")
```

sometimes its prints,

```
 keys: ["one", "two", "three"]
 Values: [1, 2, 3]
```

and sometimes its prints,

```
keys: ["three", "one", "two"]
Values: [3, 1, 2]
```

each time, whenever I run the code, I will get different output.

How I can get the output in the same sequence for keys and values always. Both keys and values must be printed in array bases on which key/value they stored in the dictionary.

If this is not possible with dictionaries, then is there an alternative way to store and get values like this?

Comment: Would `Array(sampleDic)` (which is an array of key value pairs) be good enough for you? Or do you want exactly 2 arrays?

Comment: Array(sampleDic) - this also won't work, It will give different output each time. I need actually 2 arrays one is for key and one is for values.

Comment: [Here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html#ID113) you can learn more about the Dictonary type in Swift. Only you knows what order you wants your values in so it's not easy to understand what solution you want.

Comment: samo, samo...  You can't do it.  Read similar topics.

Comment: @MKiOS What you need is an array and a struct with a key/value property

Answer (score 2):

Dictionaries stores *mappings* between keys and values, not a *list* of key value pairs, so there is no order.

If you want an order, you can *give* it one by sorting the key value pairs, e.g. by the keys

```
ket kvp = Array(sampelDic).sorted { $0.key < $1.key }
```

This produces a `[(String, Any)]`. If you actually want a `[String]` and a `[Any]`, you can write an `unzip` function (from [answer by Rob](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46044610/5133585)):

```
func unzip<K, V>(_ array: [(key: K, value: V)]) -> ([K], [V]) {
    var keys = [K]()
    var values = [V]()

    keys.reserveCapacity(array.count)
    values.reserveCapacity(array.count)

    array.forEach { key, value in
        keys.append(key)
        values.append(value)
    }

    return (keys, values)
}
```

Now you can do:

```
let (keys, values) = unzip(kvp)
print("Keys:", keys)
print("Values:", values)
```

Comment: its printing following output, Keys: ["one", "three", "two"]
Values: [1, 3, 2]

Comment: @MKiOS It will _always_ print that. Is that not what you want? I quote: " in the same sequence for keys and values always"